# Getting captions of windows

Tags: vb.net-2010

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim proc As New EnumWindProc(AddressOf EnumChild), i As Int32
    Dim hwnd() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
    Dim FormTitle As String
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    For i = 0 To hwnd.GetUpperBound(0)
        Children = String.Empty
        EnumChildWindows(hwnd(i).MainWindowHandle, proc, IntPtr.Zero)
        RetVal = GetWindowText(hwnd(i).Handle, FormTitle, Int16.MaxValue)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(FormTitle & " " & hwnd(i).ToString & Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return) & Children)
    Next i
End Sub
```

For some reason, I am only getting the first 2 lines of windows. If I remove the GetWindowTest line of code, I get all the windows, yet with no caption.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don try with **Process**, here an example to get the current opened windows titles:

```
    For Each P As Process In (From item In Process.GetProcesses Where item.MainWindowTitle.Trim <> vbNullString)
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(P.MainWindowTitle)
    Next
```